# Error during setup:di:compile - Incompatible argument type

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm getting following errors on running setup:di:compile in my magento 2.

> Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface. Actual type: array;
>
> Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory. Actual type: array;

Code responsible for the error is as follows

```
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreate,
    PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Save $giftMessageSave,
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
    \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message $messageHelper,
    StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    StockStateInterface $stockState,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_messageHelper = $messageHelper;
    $this->_wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
    $this->_giftMessageSave = $giftMessageSave;
    $this->_taxConfig = $taxConfig;
    $this->_taxData = $taxData;
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    $this->stockState = $stockState;
    parent::__construct($context, $sessionQuote, $orderCreate, $priceCurrency, $data);
}
```

And

```
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $typeConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->typeConfig = $typeConfig;
}
```

In my Layout I'm calling like this

```
        <block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\Create\Items" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/items.phtml" name="items">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items\Grid" template="Magento_Sales::quote/create/items/grid.phtml" name="items_grid">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Coupons" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/form.phtml" name="coupons">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Coupons\Form" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/coupons/form.phtml" name="form" />
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The error message speak for themselves: You type hint a certain type/contract, but when you call the method/constructor, you provide an array as parameter.
You should post the calling code to provide some context.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a stupid question but did you clear magento cache before executing your command ?

I also had issues when updating __construct, but was fixed when clearing cache.

Answer (score 0):

keep your constructor function like this

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $typeConfig
) {
    $this->typeConfig = $typeConfig;
}
```

Now Compile and Check

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass all argument to its parent constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreate,
    PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Save $giftMessageSave,
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
    \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message $messageHelper,
    StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    StockStateInterface $stockState,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_messageHelper = $messageHelper;
    $this->_wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
    $this->_giftMessageSave = $giftMessageSave;
    $this->_taxConfig = $taxConfig;
    $this->_taxData = $taxData;
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    $this->stockState = $stockState;
    //Pass All Arguments To Parent
    parent::__construct($context, $sessionQuote, $orderCreate, $priceCurrency, $wishlistFactory, $giftMessageSave, $taxConfig, $taxData, $messageHelper, $stockRegistry, $stockState, $data);
}
```

Let me know if you still got error.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $typeConfig is what you want to add into your own class. 
You need to pass all the variables into parent class besides setting $this->typeConfig.

Try this

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create $orderCreate,
    PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Save $giftMessageSave,
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
    \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message $messageHelper,
    StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    StockStateInterface $stockState,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $typeConfig // your variable
) {
   $this->typeConfig = $typeConfig; // your variable
   parent::__construct(
              $context, 
              $sessionQuote, 
              $orderCreate, 
              $priceCurrency, 
              $wishlistFactory, 
              $giftMessageSave, 
              $taxConfig, 
              $taxData, 
              $messageHelper, 
              $stockRegistry, 
              $stockState, 
              $data
    );
}
```